# Two survey datasets and chow test

Tags: r

I have to create a dummy variable by year in R Studio. The problem is that in the ESS Survey there are no year variables interpreted for the waves.

For example, Round 4 is 2008 and Round 6 is 2016. How can I create a dummy variable and calculate my regressions from these two datasets? Do I have to merge these datasets first?

The final step then would be to do a chow test to be sure there where no breaks in my regression.

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Call:
lm(formula = gincdif ~ rlgdgr + edulevel + gndr + agegroup + 
    newweight, data = mydataone)
Would this help? 
Some of the variables are these. My data names only the production date of the dataset, the wave and the year the interview started/ended. I was told that to create a chow. test I had to create first a dummy variable by year for instance: 2008=0, 2016=1 and then multiply it with every coefficient to get the results of the test: agegroup*2016+edulevel*2016 etc...